# buildspec.yml file for Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot project named "BikeService". I am generating a **war** file for this project by using the following command in the pom.xml file

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Now I want to deploy this on **Elastic Beanstalk** which I have creating using

```
Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.3.6
```

After uploading the code the deployment is successful and the Health of the environment is OK but on running the environment URL it is showing **HTTP 404 - Not Found**.

I am using the following buildspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo In the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - mvn install
  post_build:
    commands:
    - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
  - target/bike-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
  - scripts/*
```

Comment: When you login to your EB instance, and `curl` your app from the inside, does it work as expected on the port you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was solved after a lot of researching.

The issue was with the buildspec.yml file.

I am posting the correct buildspec.yml file in case anyone searches for it in the future.

The following file if for a **Spring Boot project with war packaging**.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo In the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
  post_build:
    commands:
    - echo Build completed on `date`
    - mvn package
    - mv target/bike-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war bike-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
artifacts:
  files:
  - bike-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
  - .ebextensions/**/*
```